# Cannot make table in Texmaker 5.02

Tags: tables

I am new in LaTeX. I have seen similar problem around here but I cannot find a particular solution for my case (or I don't understand the solution). I use Texmaker 5.0.2. I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

The issue came up when I generated a standard table like this:

```
\begin{tabular}{ c c}
\hline 
H & G \\ 
\hline 
2 & 3 \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular}
```

[image]

Giving the error message:

> ! Missing # inserted in alignment preamble.  \cr
>   l.15 \begin{tabular}{ c c} There should be exactly one # between &'s,
>   when an \halign or \valign is being set up. In this case you had none,
>   so I've put one in; maybe that will work. ! Extra alignment tab has
>   been changed to \cr.  \endtemplate l.17 H & G \ You have
>   given more \span or & marks than there were in the preamble to the
>   \halign or \valign now in progress. So I'll assume that you meant to
>   type \cr instead. ! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
>    \endtemplate l.19 2 & 3 \ You have given more \span or &
>   marks than there were in the preamble to the \halign or \valign now in
>   progress. So I'll assume that you meant to type \cr instead.

I have used this setup:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage{xparse,nameref}
\NewDocumentCommand{\chapref}{s m}{Chapter~\ref{#2}\IfBooleanF{#1}{ \nameref{#2}}}
\usepackage[super,numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts,amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{mathdots,mathtools}
\usepackage{ftnxtra}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{bibunits}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}%citation links
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[raggedright]{titlesec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[Bjornstrup]{fncychap}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
```

Comment: Because your example it seems you have been forgotten to use the double backslash for finish the row of the table.

Comment: @Aradnix: The example seems to be correct, but `array` should be loaded after `ftnxtra`, apparently, since it redefines `\@tabular` and `\@endtabular`, conflicting with previous versions of that command

Comment: Of course, this preamble is quite messy!

Comment: The package `latexsym` has been deprecated since ca. 1995. Why are you loading it -- especially since you're also loading `amssymb`, the package that succeeded `latexsym`?

Comment: Thank you all. I could solve it by moving array package before ftnxtra as @Aradnix pointed out.

Comment: @Wud: No, `array` must be loaded **after** `ftnxtra`... You already have the wrong loading order ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The `ftnxtra` package redefines `\@tabular` and `\@endtabular`, which conflicts with the extensions for `tabular` provided by `array`, leading to errors.

Just load `ftnxtra` (if really needed) **before** `array` in order to compile this document.

```
%\documentclass{article}


\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage{xparse,nameref}
\NewDocumentCommand{\chapref}{s m}{Chapter~\ref{#2}\IfBooleanF{#1}{ \nameref{#2}}}
\usepackage[super,numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts,amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{multicol}
%\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{mathdots,mathtools}
\usepackage{ftnxtra}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{bibunits}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[raggedright]{titlesec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[Bjornstrup]{fncychap}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}

\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}%citation links


\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{cc}
\hline 
H & G \\ 
\hline 
2 & 3 \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you @Christian Hupfer. I meant to say I loaded 'array' after 'ftnxtra'.